# Track selected Clicks from Email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a newsletter email where we have various articles with links. I want to report to show only selected click on links from email? For example I want to track link clicks for only article 1 and 3? Is it possible?

Or other scenario, I have links in header and footer as well as in body section. I do not want to track clicks for header and footer but track only in body section?

I tried it using %%=BeginImpressionRegion(1)=%% and %%=EndImpressionRegion(1)=%% but it did not work. Email was actually showing clicks for other article as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid click tracking for certain links you can build the links using AMPScript like: More info ([How to output full formed URL with ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224552/how-to-output-full-formed-url-with-ampscript))

```
%%[
var @myLink
set @myLink = 'http://link.com'
]%%

<a href="%%=v(@myLink)=%%">click here</a>
```

If you want to report on specific link clicks you can add an alias to the links as well like:

```
<a href="%%=v(@myLink)=%%" alias="article1">click here</a>
```

You can then query the _click data view with a query automation to report on the specific link clicks in a data extension.